# Como fazer um DePARA no SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

```
|        cliente      |
id  | cpf  | cpf_valido
2   | 1234 |  1
3   | 1234 |  1
5   | 4567 |  0
```

e preciso montar a tabela assim

```
|        de_para    |
 id  | id_para | cpf 
 2   |    3    |1234
 3   |    3    |1234 
 5   |    5    |4567
```

Resumindo, gerar um depara para os cpfs com o apontamento para o maior id se o cpf for valido
se o cpf for invalido manter o mesmo id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue uma sugestão para testes utilizando a função *Max* com a cláusula *Over*:

```
select
    id,
    case when cpf_valido = 1 
        then max(id) over(partition by cpf)
        else id
    end as id_para,
    cpf
from cliente
```

Comment: Opa, ajudou muito, deixou o processo rapido, do jeito que eu estava fazendo estava muito lento.

Comment: Sílvio, bom te ver por aqui. O Stack Overflow ganha com sua participação.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.id
       CASE cpf_valido
         WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT MAX(t2.id)
                        FROM tabela t2
                       WHERE t2.cpf = t1.cpf)
         ELSE t1.id
       END AS id_para,
       t1.cpf
  FROM tabela t1
```